# Imagebutton not showing in android?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I am trying to add an image button with an image to my page, but when I load the application; the image button is not appearing.

Does anyone have any advice?

XML:(it is the top image button)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.application.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/txt_Password"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getSelectedItems"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_message"
    android:onClick="btnGetSelectedItems_Click"
    android:text="@string/getSelectedItemsButton_Message"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="openOptions"
    android:text="Button" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: Did you tried with another image?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the solution was presented by SMR in the answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
```

from the `ImageButton`

it is displaying below button and that is why it is outside the visible area.

Comment: Ah yes that was the problem haha. Thankyou +1, I will accept this answer when the timer is up :)

Comment: happy to help you cheerz :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.application.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"        
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/txt_Password"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/txt_Password"
android:visibility="invisible" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
android:id="@+id/getSelectedItems"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_message"
android:onClick="btnGetSelectedItems_Click"
android:text="@string/getSelectedItemsButton_Message"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
android:text="@string/button_send" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
android:visibility="invisible" >

</ListView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
android:onClick="openOptions"
android:text="Button" />
```